# Reusable components using Tera/Zola

Tags: static-site, static-site-generation, tera, zola

I am making a theme based on another Zola theme and it is going great so far. The only problem I have run into is the following:
I am using Tailwind. It works well, but because Tailwind classes can add up, the Tailwind team reccomends using components. I know how to do this in Vue using Slots, but I have no idea how to do this with Tera/Zola or if this is even possible at all. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem elegantly in Zola/Tera

I am now using the following hack. It works, but it is quite ugly and requires 2 files per "component".

~It enables me to use consistent classes for links:

_startlink.html

```html
<div class="tailwind classes here">
```

_endlink.html

```html
</div>
```

When using the "component"

```html
{% include "_startlink.html" %}
  <a  href="/blog">blog</a>
{% include "_endlink.html" %}
```

## My intuition says to do something like the following:

_link.html

```html
<a class="Tailwind classes here" href=link> {%block link%} {% endblock link %} </a>
```

Using the component:

```
{% block link link="example.com" %} Link to example.com {% endblock link %}
```

Edit: I found a new way. I prefer it over the other one, but I still don't like it:

```
{% set tl_link = "tailwind classes here" %}
<a class="{{ tl_link }}"> text here </a>
```